# Как реализовать вывод пользователей кто онлайн?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Как реализовать вывод пользователей кто онлайн? Имеетеся система регистрации как сделать подсажите

Comment: http://php.su/articles/?cat=examples&page=039 я использовал эту статью все сделал как там сказано но мне еще надо знать как сделать так чтобы зарегистрированных пользователей было написанно имя кто онлайн а вот система регистрации которую я задействовал http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=37&id=506
ну к прмеру я могу вывести из базы всех пользователей на страницу
что вот мне дальше делать

Comment: если можете это сделать то помогите

Comment: пример что мне надо внизу http://testphp.ucoz.ru сайта но там внизу еще и пользователи отображаютя мне как бы так надо

Comment: Отредактировал свой ответ, погляди, попробуй

Comment: а вы смотрели ссылки то что я отправлял

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in S:\home\stars-speeds.ru\www\online.php on line 57
может в скайпе обговорим palosh65 я ее поставил и ничего

Comment: Давай свой скайп. Тут я точку с запятой забыл. после echo <pre>"&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;".$row2['flname']."&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;"</pre>

Comment: Он не работает как его завести сам online.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если вы не знаете языка, то Вам на фриланс. Если же знаете, то наведу на идею: сделать в бд таблицу с онлайном пользователей. И когда пользователь заходит на сайт, забивать его id и время визита в неё и каждый раз при заходе на какую-либо страницу обновлять время визита последнего. Далее, на странице вывода списка онлайн, вывести всех пользователей из созданной таблицы, у которых, например, время  последнего визита менее 2минут назад. Если больше, то удалить эту запись. Если что-то не понятно, спрашивайте.

Ну, во-первых создание таблицы будет выглядеть таким образом:

```
CREATE TABLE online (
  id int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  ip varchar(20) NOT NULL default '0',
  iduser varchar(80) NOT NULL default '0',
  unix varchar(60) NOT NULL default '',
  KEY id (id)
)
```

Код не проверял, будут ошибки, пиши - отладим вместе
Теперь нужно на всех страницах сделать

```
include 'online.php';
 on_line();
```

А вот если нужно вывести таблицу пользователей онлайн, то так:

```
 on_line(true);
```

Вот код online.php:

```
------ Файл online.php
/ ф-я подсчитывает пользователей на линии; возвращает кол-во пользователей в
отформатированном виде, т.е. для вывода результата нужно лишь прописать в
нужном месте типа: echo on_line(); /
 function on_line($echousers = false) {
 $host = "localhost"; // хост, где расположена база данных MySql
 $db_name = ""; // имя базы данных; как правило совпадает с именем юзера
                // (переменная ниже), хотя я категорически против одинаковых
                // имен, ориентируясь на защиту...
 $db_user = ""; // пользователь, которому разрешен доступ к базе
 $db_password = ""; // пароль пользователя
 $wine = 300; // точность он-лайн (секунды); время, в течении которого
              // пользователя, зашедшего на страничку, мы считаем находящимся
              // на сайте
 $table_online = "online"; // имя таблицы
// делаем доступной глобальную переменную ИП-адреса
 global $REMOTE_ADDR;
 // соединяемся с сервером MySQL и выбираем нужную базу
 mysql_connect($host,$db_user,$db_password) or die(mysql_error());
 mysql_select_db($db_name) or die(mysql_error());
// удаляем всех, кто уже пробыл $wine секунд или у кого ИП текущий
$sql_update = "DELETE FROM $table_online WHERE unix+$wine < ".time().
              " OR ip = '$_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR]'";
$result_update = mysql_query($sql_update) or die(mysql_error());
// вставляем свою запись
$sql_insert = "INSERT INTO $table_online(id,ip,iduser, unix) VALUES ('','$_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR]', '$_SESSION[userid]', '".time()."')";
$result_insert = mysql_query($sql_insert) or die(mysql_error());
// считаем уников он-лайн
$sql_sel = "SELECT id FROM $table_online";
$result_sel = mysql_query($sql_sel) or die(mysql_error());
$online_people = mysql_num_rows($result_sel); // кол-во On-Line пользователей
$online_people = (string) $online_people; // приводим к строковому типу
                                          // (так надо.. см. дальше)
$rain = strlen($online_people) - 1; // номер последнего символа в числе
                                    // on-line юзеров
// форматирование вывода (я все сделал за вас =)
 if($online_people[$rain]==2||$online_people[$rain]==3
||$online_people[$rain]==4
||(strlen($online_people)!=1&&$online_people[strlen($online_people)-2]!=1))
// $line - переменная, определяющая формат вывода
 $line = "человека"; else $line = "человек";
// возвращаем результат
if($echousers==false)
 return "На сайте <strong>".$online_people."</strong>$line";
else{
echo "<table>";
while($row_sel = mysql_fetch_array($result_sel)){
$res2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE pk_user='$row_sel[iduser]'");
$row2 = mysql_fetch_array($res2);
echo "<tr><td>".$row2['flname']."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
}
}
```

Comment: хм а мануалка есть какая-нибудь

Comment: язык знаю но не слишком много дело в том что я еще пока что не профи

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/index.php
Вот официальный мануал по php. Но, думаю, его смотреть нужно после изучения языка. Например, есть хорошая книга: Основы программирования на РНР (Ларри Ульман)

Comment: Ну да. Впринципе, можно поискать статью-урок по этой теме.

Comment: У Вас самописный скрипт? ИЛи может CMS какая? Например, wordpress или joomla?

Comment: нет вы не поняли я зык я знаю даже неплохо ну как сказать я не такой нуб  у меня даже сайт есть вот просто нужно доработать а знакомых нету ч тобы с этим помогли http://www.stars-speed.ru

Comment: Ну если Вы систему регистрации сами делали, то у вас должно получится. Вам что-то конкретное не понятно, или всё не понятно из того, что я написал?

Comment: самописный сайт